# App slows down after repeated calls to CoreData

Tags: swift, performance, core-data

I have a master-detail view where a parameter from the master view filters results on a detail view. I use storyboards and pass the parameter in a segue.

Everything works fine except for when I click on the back button and select an item again. That's when the loading gets slower. In the beginning, it's slightly slow but the more I do the back and select exercise the slower it gets.

I think the issue is with core data no freeing up memory after I go back to the master view controller. But I am not sure. Wonder if there's any workaround to fix this?

Here's my code for the detail view:

```
 static func findByChapterId(_ id: Int16) -> NSFetchedResultsController<Verse>{

    let context = getContext()

    let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Verse>
    fetchRequest = Verse.fetchRequest()
    fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "chapterId == %@", NSNumber(value: id as Int16))
    let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "verseId", ascending: true)
    let sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = sortDescriptors
    fetchRequest.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false


    let controller = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: context, sectionNameKeyPath: "chapterId", cacheName: nil)
    do {
        try controller.performFetch()
    } catch {
        fatalError("Failed to fetch entities: \(error)")
    }

    return controller
}
```

Comment: Maybe not related (but could be) creating a brand new fetched results controller for each chapter is pretty cumbersome. Create the controller once (as `lazy var`) and change only the fetch request. And `id` **is** `Int16`. The bridge cast `as Int16` is redundant.

Comment: @vadian any example or ref you can point me to? Thanks

Comment: The Apple iOS Core Data template declares the FRC as `lazy var`. Then just assign a new fetch request to the instance and perform a fetch.

Comment: Can I still wrap it in a method like the one I have here? @vadian

Comment: Yes, but you don't need to return something as the controller is always the same.